# Changing welcome screen of Nginx

Tags: nginx, meteor

Hi i have setup nginx  and works fine. I have added some config to accept the subdomain and that is also working fine no problem.
 My major concern is i have a meteor app that takes the username and creates nginx subdomain config in the fly. and currently i have listed * in my A/AAAA record in server so it accepts all subdomain.
 now i wanna show different view if the user request the subdomain that is not created in nginx config. 
for eg,
i have setup subdomain A,B in nginx config pointing different application 
A.example.com //works fine
B.example.com //works fine

if i Enter 
C.example.com // shows me welcome to nginx screen 
I wanna show my custom page there 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Meteor, rather it is about setting up your nginx's default page. Try the below links

http://gpiot.com/blog/setup-default-server-landing-page-with-nginx/

[NGinx Default public www location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674867/nginx-default-public-www-location)