# Best practice - document root, git and dist/src folders

Tags: url, subdomain, git, document-root

First of all, I'm sorry if this question is pretty much a best practice question, rather than me asking for some help from you guys.

Basically, I'm new to webmaster stuff (as I am a web developer, but I've never had to manage domains / hosting before.

The way I usually work is with having the source code and the distribution code into two different folders, as some of my source gets compiled into the dist folder (some, not everything!)

I also use git as a source code tracker and then on the server I use git command line to push, pull switch branch and so on.

So, the problem I've got is that in git I have both folders (both dist and src) that get pushed.

Let me write down an example:

let's say I have a domain called `www.mydomain.com`

When I clone the repository into `www.mydomain.com`, the server root, if I navigate to the domain, above looks like this:

```
index of:
src/
dist/
```

and os to have the proper website, the URL needs to be `www.mydomain.com/dist`.

If I append dist at the end, it works, but I don't like it. I so tried to change the server document root in my Cpanel account from `/domains/mydomain.com` to `/domains/mydomain.com/dist` hoping that this would tell the website to look directly into the dist folder as a root document folder and not the level up.

That, unfortunately, didn't work.

I also tried with a redirect, but again, dist gets appended at the end of the URL.

I also started to look into `git post-commit` hooks, but I'm not sure that's the right path to follow.

> Basically, after this very long question, all I'd like to know is a
>   best practice to handle two folders pushed on the server with git, but
>   having the URL point to one without having the URL to display the
>   subfolder name. Is that possible? do I need to setup the .htaccess
>   file to do that or is something that needs to be done when setting up
>   the domain name?

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: You are looking for a very basic rewrite rule.  This is not really a programming question.  It was a mistake to migrate it here.

Comment: I have no idea who migrated it here to be fair as i know that's not a programming question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess rewrite to redirect root URL to subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory)

Comment: Depends on the web server but at least that should give you some terminology to google.

Comment: ok thanks i'll give it a go

Comment: I agree that it was a mistake to migrate this web-root question to stackoverflow. I suggest migrating this question to serverfault.com or perhaps returning it to webmasters.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Nick, you probably need to edit some ".conf" file. What web server software are you using? If you are using Apache, this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server . If you are using nginx, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674867/nginx-default-public-www-location answers your question. Or are you using something else?

Comment: @DavidCary thanks for the comment. I'll have a look and let you know if it helped me :)
and yes, I am using apache

Comment: just a quick thing: if I change the apache config file, it will change the root on all the server, right? not really on a per-folder basis...am I correct?
I am happy with the default root directory being var/www, but each subdomain (or addon domains - basically all the domains hosted on my server) need to have a different root and not all the same one...

Comment: Nick, "How do I set up http.conf" sounds like an excellent question for http://serverfault.com/ , possibly using their "[apache2](http://serverfault.com/tags/apache2/info)" tag. ( "[Ask the user to create a new question after being asked in comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318267/ask-the-user-to-create-a-new-question-after-being-asked-in-comments)" ).

Comment: ok, i'll post it there. Thanks

Comment: just as a cress reference: http://serverfault.com/questions/831341/apache-2-document-root-git-and-dist-src-folders