# Nginx reading site files from incorrect root

Tags: php, ssl, nginx, https, config

Ever since I set up HTTPS through SSL in my sites-enabled/default config, Nginx is reading from `/usr/share/www/html` rather than `/var/www/html`. There are no references to `/usr/.../html` in any of my files (when I use `grep -r`) so I have no clue why this is happening.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name MY_WEBSITE.TLD; # Before you ask, yes
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    root /var/www/html;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Clearly I've defined the root. Why isn't it working?

Comment: Have you tried defining the root in the SSL configuration section?

Comment: Which is the ssl configuration section? You mean the second server block? If so, yes I have.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.   How many sites on this installation?  You can set root in the "http" section ... does that do it?  I run a little nGinx but haven't done much server config with it ... sorry.

Comment: Only one domain. I tried setting it in the http section... but now I just get a 403 forbidden error...

Comment: Do you need server_name in both containers/sections?

Comment: I've tried both ways. Didn't work.

Comment: Is this happening on requests for all files, or only php ones?

Comment: Actually, when I type in the url for a PHP file, it downloads it... but with JS files for example it just displays them as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Your config describes 2 separate servers - not 2 ports on one server.  It is obviously convenient that you can include them in a single file in `sites-available/`, but technically they are different, independent servers, and you could split each `server` block into a different `sites-available/` config file.

Bearing that in mind, check what you have for each server.  You have one server on port 80, which has a `root` specified.  All fine there.

You have another server on port 443.  This is a completely separate server, not the same server on another port.  It has no `root` specified, so nginx will fall back to some default root location, determined by compile-time switches or distro-specific variables, [as described in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674867/nginx-default-public-www-location).

Comment: But when I specify a root, it still uses usr/.../html. EDIT: I specified as the fifth line in the second (SSL) server{} block.

Comment: @ColonelHedgehog The key is *where* did you specify a `root`? And did you restart nginx after doing that?

Comment: OK, after a refresh, it seems to be using the correct root. However... now it downloads my php files instead of viewing them. So it looks like I've traded one problem for another.

Comment: @ColonelHedgehog @ColonelHedgehog Yes, that's a new problem.  My guess is your `location /` is overriding the `location ~ \.php$`.  Do you really need both?  Try moving your `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` into your `location ~ \.php$`, and deleting the `location /`.

Comment: Didn't seem to change anything. Here is my current file: https://pastebin.com/9giy4yZ2 - Note: if I add another "server_name" declaration in the second server{} block, then it gives me 502 bad gateway but does NOT download the files.

Comment: @ColonelHedgehog 1. Don't specify `root` 2x inside the same `server`. 2. Having 2x `default_server` inside one `server` block also looks strange, try removing them both for now. 3. What is `/scripts` in your `fastcgi_param`? Typically that is something like `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`. 4. I think you need a `server_name` - what are you using, and check the logs, what is the real error?

Comment: Another change I made. It turns out there was another server {} block in my nginx.conf. I made changes so both files look like this: https://pastebin.com/GHTLL8Vj EDIT: I didn't see your response yet. Trying those now.

Comment: Turned out I had the wrong directory for php-fpm specified. Wow.

Answer (score 0):

Aaaaand it all leads back to me specifying the wrong directory for php7.0-fpm. Because of course it does! Thank you to @Don't Panic and @Keven_Kinsey for helping me out. It finally loads properly.