# Unable to locate root directory of a web app in NGINX?

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean

I'm struggling with a NGINX based web app , i need to find its root directory that's being served. Its a subdomain and a simple `nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/app.refridge.com` it has the following contents.

```
    ##
    # You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
    # of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
    # http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
    # http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
    # http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
    #
    # Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
    # file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
    #
    # Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
    ##

    # Default server configuration
    #

    server {
        listen *:80;
        server_name app.refridge.com;

        location / {
            rewrite     ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
        }

    }

server {
     listen *:443 ssl;
     server_name app.refridge.com;
     access_log /var/log/nginx/app.refridge.com-access.log;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/app.refridge.com-error.log;

        # SSL configuration
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/STAR_refridge_com-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/star_refridge_com.key;


        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
```

There's no root defined even for port 80 and 443 but still the website loads. I mean is there anything i'm missing i need to find the files and do a backup thats why.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S it's a DigitalOcean droplet.

**UPDATE: ** I think there a reverse proxy setup

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;                                                                                      }
```

Assuming 3000 port so this is a node.js application but still there should be files which i can access and do a backup.

Thanks

Comment: Check this linke https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674867/nginx-default-public-www-location might be helpful for you.

Comment: @iamimran Yeah , but as i updated my  question there's a reverse proxy setup and maybe that's why im unable to locate the files though.

Comment: Other option you can use is try searching for some specific files (css, js, etc) from terminal.