# how is Nginx finding default root

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I just installed `nginx` using `brew` and its default config is located at `/usr/local/etc/nginx`. The server configuration in default `conf` file is as below (only small portion pasted)

```
server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
...
}
```

The location from which the `index.html` is being served is `/usr/local/var/www/`. Now, looking at the above configuration, I don't understand how `nginx` goes to `/usr/local/var/www/` to look for default file? Is there a different configuration that directs `nginx` to look into that folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If a value of the [root](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) directive is relative, the full path is composed using the nginx prefix. See [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11128102/9783845) for details.
2. [In the nginx Homebrew formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/8f0c6ba832cb38e7106d0e64d2ea23013649649d/Formula/nginx.rb#L44) the `--prefix` is set to the Homebrew prefix:

```
      --prefix=#{prefix}
```

3. The default Homebrew prefix is `/usr/local` [on Intel](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-should-i-install-homebrew-in-the-default-location).
4. Thus, the root is `html` → `/usr/local/html` (the nginx prefix + the relative path).
5. [In the nginx Hombebrew formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/8f0c6ba832cb38e7106d0e64d2ea23013649649d/Formula/nginx.rb#L107) this location is symlinked to `#{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/var/www`, that is, to `/usr/local/var/www`:

> ```
> # nginx's docroot is #{prefix}/html, this isn't useful, so we symlink it
> # to #{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/var/www. The reason we symlink instead of patching
> # is so the user can redirect it easily to something else if they choose.
> ```

Comment: such a great explanation.

Comment: Let's say I want `index.html` at the same path as `nginx.conf`. Would that be possible? At i.e. `home/user/project1/`.

Comment: @KcFnMi easily: set `root` to the prefix dir (`root .;`) and run nginx with the prefix path set to the current dir (`nginx -p . -c nginx.conf`)

Answer (score -2):

Setting it like this `root html` makes nginx use relative location.
The easiest way is to have the root written with the full desired path like this

`root   /var/www/html;`